# unfortunately,project has stopped in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

The code is all about taking the zodiac sign as the input in the 1st activity and when clicked OK navigates to the next activity where it displays the details as the web view of that particular zodiac sign. When ever I try to run the code in the emulator or in my mobile I get a warning project is continuously stopping and the application closes.

```
MainActivity.java

  package com.example.project;

  import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.text.Editable;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.webkit.WebView;
  import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

WebView webView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
public void send(View v){
    Intent goToSecond = new Intent();
    goToSecond.setClass(this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(goToSecond);
    String sign = ((EditText)(findViewById(R.id.editText_sign))).getText().toString();
    goToSecond.putExtra("sign", sign);
    startActivity(goToSecond);
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="100"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:ignore="Autofill"
android:background="@drawable/signwheel2">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
    android:background="#EFE9E9"
    android:text="@string/zodiac" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText_sign"
    android:layout_width="223dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:background="#FDFCFC"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/libra"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="127dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="send"
    android:text="@android:string/ok"
    android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>
```

SecondActivity.java

```
package com.example.project;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    Intent caller = getIntent();
    String sign = caller.getStringExtra("sign");
    assert sign != null;
    switch (sign) {
        case "Taurus":
            webView.loadUrl("https://www.chatelaine.com/living/horoscopes/taurus-zodiac-sign/");
            break;
        case "Aries":
            webView.loadUrl("https://www.chatelaine.com/living/horoscopes/aries-zodiac-sign/");
            break;
        case "Leo":
            webView.loadUrl("https://www.chatelaine.com/living/horoscopes/leo-zodiac-sign/");
            break;
        case "Pisces":
            webView.loadUrl("https://www.chatelaine.com/living/horoscopes/pisces-zodiac-sign/");
            break;
        case "Scoripo":
            webView.loadUrl("https://www.chatelaine.com/living/horoscopes/scorpio-zodiac-sign/");
            break;
        case "Sagittarius":
            webView.loadUrl("https://www.chatelaine.com/living/horoscopes/sagittarius-zodiac-sign/");
            break;
        case "Gemini":
            webView.loadUrl("https://www.chatelaine.com/living/horoscopes/gemini-zodiac-sign/");
            break;
        case "Virgo":
            webView.loadUrl("https://www.chatelaine.com/living/horoscopes/virgo-zodiac-sign/");
            break;
        case "Libra":
            webView.loadUrl("https://www.chatelaine.com/living/horoscopes/libra-zodiac-sign/");
            break;
        case "Capricorn":
            webView.loadUrl("https://www.chatelaine.com/living/horoscopes/capricorn-zodiac-sign/");
            break;
        case "Aquarius":
            webView.loadUrl("https://www.chatelaine.com/living/horoscopes/aquarius-zodiac-sign/");
            break;
        case "Cancer":
            webView.loadUrl("https://www.chatelaine.com/living/horoscopes/cancer-zodiac-sign/");
            break;
        default:
            String message1 = "Please check the spelling";
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
    }

}
}
```

activity_second.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SecondActivity">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="409dp"
    android:layout_height="729dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.project">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat:

```
04-22 14:59:17.888 3355-3355/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
04-22 14:59:18.026 3355-3355/com.example.project W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
/data/app/com.example.project-2/lib/x86
04-22 14:59:18.045 3355-3355/com.example.project D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-22 14:59:18.046 3355-3355/com.example.project E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.project, PID: 3355
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

******************************************************************************
* The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
* should follow the instructions here:                                       *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
* to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
* Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
******************************************************************************


    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5156)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4748)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4688)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

******************************************************************************
* The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
* should follow the instructions here:                                       *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
* to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
* Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
******************************************************************************


    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzyc.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads- 
    lite@@19.1.0:33)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play- 
    services-ads-lite@@19.1.0:3)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5153)
        ... 10 more
    04-22 14:59:20.745 3355-3355/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3355 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Did you follow the detailed instructions in the error log?

Comment: yes, I did but facing the same problem at second activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `startActivity` twice, also `.setClass` is not needed:

```
   public void send(View v){
     String sign = ((EditText)(findViewById(R.id.editText_sign))).getText().toString();
        Intent goToSecond = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        //startActivity(goToSecond);//Comment this line
        goToSecond.putExtra("sign", sign);
       startActivity(goToSecond);
}
```

In `secondactivity` you are doing `findViewById` before `setContentView` add the below line after `setContentView` in `SecondActivity`

```
webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

Your Exception says there is a nullpointer exception so add a null check to your code:

```
String sign = "";
if (getIntent != null){
Intent caller = getIntent();
String sign = caller.getStringExtra("sign");
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: facing the same problem even.

Comment: @PradyumnaShashank are you seeing same error log? Can you update the error log?

Comment: @PradyumnaShashank your log in question details about ads but in your code you have not used add any where have you added that in gradle?

Comment: * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
Gradle sync started
Gradle sync finished in 1 s 676 ms (from cached state)
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project C:\Users\Pradyumna\AndroidStudioProjects\project
Emulator: emulator: WARNING: EmulatorService.cpp:448: Cannot find certfile: C:\Users\Pradyumna\.android\emulator-grpc.cer security will be disabled.
Emulator: Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554
Gradle build finished in 23 s 235 ms
Install successfully finished in 3 s 926 ms.
Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: this is the log which is being seen after making the update you have mentioned. @Keshav1234

Comment: @PradyumnaShashank this does not specify anything, once the installation is finished you can see an error in logcat, you can filter the logcat to show only the exeception. If you add that log I can tell what might be the issue.

Comment: 04-23 21:07:44.282 3842-3842/com.example.project E/SysUtils: ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus

Comment: 04-23 21:07:44.297 3842-3842/com.example.project E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
04-23 21:07:44.297 3842-3842/com.example.project E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)

Comment: 04-23 21:07:44.391 3842-3842/com.example.project E/DataReductionProxySettingListener: No DRP key due to exception:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.webview.chromium.Drp

Comment: 04-23 21:07:44.419 3842-3842/com.example.project E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.project, PID: 3842 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.project/com.example.project.SecondActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.hashCode()' on a null object reference
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)

Comment: ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

Comment: com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.hashCode()' on a null object reference com.example.project.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.java:22)Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237).Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)

Comment: .ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) .ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java).ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) atActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

Comment: these are logcat errors @Keshav1234

Comment: @PradyumnaShashank check my edited answer to fix you null pointer exception. If my answer helped you please accept it as answer and upvote it.

Comment: thank you it has help me :)